# EclipseLink @AdditionalCriteria do not work with find

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

i am using [@AdditionalCriteria](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Additional_Criteria)  to add condition to a certain entity.
all the query related to this entity are working with the additional criteria except the find method of the entity manager.

it could be related to nature of the find method since it check the cache for the object directly without getting  the id from the database first.

how to let additional criteria work with find method.

```
EntityManager em;
Certain c=em.find(Certain.class,id);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, find is only going to the cache not the database, so the cache must contain data that is outside the scope of the additional criteria you have specified.  I do not recommend using filters on your entities directly as there isn't a good way to tell if you have a true representation of the data as it exists in the database or what state your entity is in when modifications might be happening.

The way to have the find method respect your additional criteria would be to force a refresh to the database.  You can either provide an [EclipseLink refresh hint](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Hints#Refresh) to the find call or explicitly call em.refresh() on the entity after the find call.

Comment: what about entities that has relation the entity with addtional criteria.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  What about them exactly?  Any query to your entity will by default pull the entity from the cache.  So if your cache doesn't reflect the latest data in the database or any changes that might affect the filter, then it needs to be forcibly refreshed (or expired).  Filters just compound the issue, as things within the referenced entity can change without a way to signal the cache that it no longer matches the entity's filter. Filters are difficult and it is sometimes better/easier just to use a query directly rather then cache/maintain the relationship in the entity